# Is there any use case for using 'L' letter after a number literal in C?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, compiler, data

I know that in C code using L after a number tells the compiler that the respective number is L.

However I do not see any practical use for this. Do modern compilers still have a use for this language construct?

If there are still use cases what would be those cases?

Comment: see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: @gnat However I am not looking for a right answer but for a practical use case of a language construct.

Comment: `long fileSize = 12345L;` In many languages the default, unadorned number is assumed to be an `int`.  Many languages hide that fact by providing implicit up-converts.  Still some languages don't and you have to be specific.  What really makes a suffix _required_ is when the default type is larger than what you need.  For example in many languages floating point numbers in code default to a `double`.  To down-convert you either need an explicit cast, or the suffix to fix it.  `float smallPi = 3.14159F;`.  Depends on your language honestly.

Comment: given that [more](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string#Literals) [literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration#Literals) [suffixes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) have been introduced: Yes, modern compilers still have a use for specifying types in literals

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the C language expressions are typed inside-out: literals have types. E.g. `123` is an int, and `123U` is an unsigned int, `123L` is a long int and so on. The type of an expression depends on the types of the subexpressions: the type of `a + b` depends on the types of `a` and `b`.

Ensuring the correct type is particularly important when doing bit-fiddling. You also have to take care for large literals that do not fit into an int (or the type of a variable you are assigning the expression value to – narrowing conversions are a common source of bugs).

However, most code should not explicitly use a `long` type or the `L` literal suffix because the size of long integers is platform dependent. Integers and long integers may even have the same size.

For portable code that needs a specific size, it is more correct to use the C99 fixed width integer types (like `int64_t`). They do not have corresponding literal suffixes, instead you have to use the literal macros like `INT64_C(123)` from `stdint.h`. These macros will apply the correct casts or platform-dependent type suffixes if necessary.

In C++ the type of an expression may affect with overloads are invoked. Notably `0`, `'\0'`, `false` and `nullptr` often behave very differently, despite all being “null” and to some degree being implicitly convertible to each other.

Comment: I don't know abour more recent standards, but in C89, the type of character literals is `int`.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Thanks, you're right. The character literal [`'c'` would have type int in C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant), though it seems its range is limited to that of a char. I never noticed this because of the implicit narrowing conversions. C++ is more sane and actually uses the char type for char literals.